# What are the Java equivalents to Linq and Entity Framework

Tags: java, linq, entity-framework

Having played with Linq (to SQL and Objects) as well as the Entity Framework from Microsoft recently, I was wondering what the non-.Net (specifically Java) equivalents are?

Comment: For Linq to objects check this one: github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light, real example:new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).toList().distinct();

Answer (score 22):

Consider using Querydsl : http://www.querydsl.com

It supports JPA/Hibernate, JDO, SQL and Collections.

Querydsl is fully type-safe, supports autocomplete in IDEs and provides a common querying syntax on top multiple backends.

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, and I wrote a [comparison to other frameworks](http://source.mysema.com/display/querydsl/Similar+frameworks) some time ago.

It is slightly biased, but shows the different emphasis

- statically typed or not
- which backends are supported
- is the interface for query construction cascading or not

Newer frameworks experiment also with closure syntax.

Comment: Why is this being flagged as spam? As far as I can see answers the question.

Comment: @Yacoby, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50038/it-doesnt-matter-what-the-question-is-theres-only-one-answer (which has been resolved by Timo nicely, in my opinion)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Java project called [JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/) which provides object querying capabilities with a SQL-like syntax.
While I haven't used it myself, I know that it is used in some heavyweight applications.

Comment: This looks pretty interesting.  It's not a database tool, but a way to use SQL to operate on Java objects (like LINQ to Objects).

Answer (score 3):

Java does not have a Linq equivalent. However Scala, a functional language that compiles to Java byte code, has something closes: an extended for loop syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JaQue](http://www.ohloh.net/p/jaque).

Answer (score 2):

For database-heavy work, [SQLJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLJ) might be an option. The downside is it's not pure Java and requires a pre-processor.

Answer (score 2):

For LINQ (LINQ to Objects to be more accurate) you can use Streams starting from Java 8

This doesn't work for databases however, only for internal objects like Collections and Lists

It is really powerfull, but not as complete as LINQ (in my opinion)

Check out this tutorial - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

As for Entity Framework there is nothing quite as powerful that I have found yet, but haven't tried all the solutions provided in the other answers

Answer (score 1):

You won't find an equivalent of LINQ unless you use the [javacc](http://java.net/projects/javacc/) to create your own equivalent.

Until that day when someone finds a viable way to do so, there are some good alternatives, such as

- Quaere: http://quaere.codehaus.org/
- jOOQ: http://www.jooq.org
- JaQu: http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html
- Linq4j: https://github.com/julianhyde/linq4j
- JSR-341: http://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/CollectionOperations

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact alternative which is universal as LINQ is. However if we are talking about LINQ to SQL then JPA is really an alternative when you use it with an IDE that supports "Inject language" feature. E.g. IDEA will do full scale completion of the JPA query within a string