# Is there any entity framework equivalent in java?

Tags: java, .net

Everyone who programmed with C# knows that there is the Entity Framework as ORM (object-relational mapper) which enable programmer to query database using only C# code.

For example, if I have a database called `Shop`, and in the `Shop` database I have `Products` table, i can get all product of `Products`table where their price is less than 2 dollar in the following way:

```
ShopEntity _Db = new ShopEntity();
List<Product> products = _Db.Products.Where(p => p.Price < 2).ToList();
```

The above code is equivalent to this SQL statement:

```
Select * From Products Where Price < 2
```

I want to know is there any framework like that in Java?

I also saw [quaere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083080/what-are-the-java-equivalents-to-linq-and-entity-framework). But it just queries collections. I want to query  against the database. There is another framework in java called [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) which does not provide good functionality for query the database.

Comment: I am confused on the down-votes with no comments. This question interested me, and was wondering why the negative rep...

Comment: I did not downvote, but this type of question runs contrary to the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And see also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Hibernate allows you to query the DB using HQL, or Hibernate Query Language, which is VERY SQL-like.  There is also EclipseLink, EJB, JDO, and many, many others.  If you want to abstract your ORM, you can use JPA on top, which "normalizes" the underlying ORM from your application.  JPA also has JPQL, which is also very SQL-like, to query objects from the DB directly.

Comment: I think i should use hibernate query language.

Comment: Even if every C# programmer knows the Entity Framework, most Java programmers don't. If you are looking for a Java library, describe the functionality you require, don't just name a foreign-language framework as reference. Did you google? Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a human operated search engine. If you are looking for something else but Hibernate, it would be very convenient if you shared with us what your exact problem with Hibernate is. My crystal ball is not working right now and it's difficult to guess what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @jarnbjo your right. I am looking for a framework in java to query database using only java code.

Comment: And if you google "framework in java to query database", one of the first hits is this page: http://java-source.net/open-source/persistence There you'll find a list of 45 Java libraries, which probably more or less all are doing what you're asking for. Why are you asking here?

Comment: @jarnbjo i have not enough experience in java. So i shared this with you for help. So there is 45 java liberaries. Which one may help me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The standard ORM API in Java it's called [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), and is part of the Java EE specification. Another alternative would be to use [Hibernate](http://hibernate.bluemars.net). Both provide their own query language ([JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html) and [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) respectively), but no query framework exists under Java that provides a direct integration at the language level the way LINQ does for C#.

Comment: JPA is not really an ORM framework, but an API specification. Hibernate is actually one of the ORM frameworks, which implements the JPA specification.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi JPA is a subset of Hibernate, it can be run inside an EJB container (say, JBoss) or outside. Hibernate is a more feature-rich option, and also can be run inside or outside an EJB container. Either one is appropriate - depending on what you actually need. It might be easier to setup JPA though, because it's part of the JEE standard. Take a look at both and pick the one that better suits your needs, it's up to you to decide which one is best - both will do fine